# How can I take random Morse code Input and output Italian words only?

Tags: python

[image: The Voynich Manuscript Glyphs represented as dash and dot count totals]

I'm using Python 3.7

To view the Voynich Manuscript:

To see my work check out Voynichman Forum:
[Voynichman](http://voynichman.freeforums.net/thread/39/voynich-morse-code-steganography-cipher)
This video also explains my work with the Voynich Manuscript:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wo2ER1Zs78U

[Jason Davies Voynich Manuscript](https://www.jasondavies.com/voynich/#f1r/0.608/0.453/2.00)

My premise is that Wilfrid Voynich constructed the Voynich Manuscript some time in 1910

This is a little complicated to describe so bear with me.  I wish to take any dot dash input from Morse code (which does not necessarily have to represent a letter in Morse code) and output Italian words only.  I want the code to find the letters for me and then put them together if they recognize a word in Italian.  I already have python code which takes normal Morse code input and just outputs anagrams in any language.  I'm not sure if anyone who aids me here needs to use an anagram engine.  I wish to have this code so I can fully decode the Voynich Manuscript.

Here is a sample narrative from Voynich to Morse to Italian translated to English:

[image: Folio 16r]

The cipher above retains the glyph relationships to the dot and dash totals which is used to build an Italian word.  Here is an example.  I have to admit there are some English words.
[image: MorseTGM]

```
print("Author Thomas O'Neil, copyright ver 0.1,VMS Italian Steganography 
Morse Code to Anagrams, August 8, 2019")

# Python program to implement Morse Code Translator 

''' 
VARIABLE KEY 
'cipher' -> 'stores the morse translated form of the english string' 
'decipher' -> 'stores the english translated form of the morse string' 
'citext' -> 'stores morse code of a single character' 
'i' -> 'keeps count of the spaces between morse characters' 
'message' -> 'stores the string to be encoded or decoded' 
'''

# Dictionary representing the morse code chart 
MORSE_CODE_DICT = { 'A':'.-', 'B':'-...', 
                'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.', 
                'F':'..-.', 'G':'--.', 'H':'....', 
                'I':'..', 'J':'.---', 'K':'-.-', 
                'L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.', 
                'O':'---', 'P':'.--.', 'Q':'--.-', 
                'R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-', 
                'U':'..-', 'V':'...-', 'W':'.--', 
                'X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--', 'Z':'--..', 
                '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--', 
                '4':'....-', '5':'.....', '6':'-....', 
                '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.', 
                '0':'-----', ', ':'--..--', '.':'.-.-.-', 
                '?':'..--..', '/':'-..-.', '-':'-....-', 
                '(':'-.--.', ')':'-.--.-',} 

# Function to encrypt the string 
# according to the morse code chart 
def encrypt(message): 
cipher = '' 
for letter in message: 
    if letter != ' ': 

        # Looks up the dictionary and adds the 
        # correspponding morse code 
        # along with a space to separate 
        # morse codes for different characters 
        cipher += MORSE_CODE_DICT[letter] + ' '
    else: 
        # 1 space indicates different characters 
        # and 2 indicates different words 
        cipher += ' '

return cipher 

# Function to decrypt the string 
# from morse to english 
def decrypt(message): 

# extra space added at the end to access the 
# last morse code 
message += ' '

decipher = '' 
citext = '' 
for letter in message: 

    # checks for space 
    if (letter != ' '): 

        # counter to keep track of space 
        i = 0

        # storing morse code of a single character 
        citext += letter 

    # in case of space 
    else: 
        # if i = 1 that indicates a new character 
        i += 1

        # if i = 2 that indicates a new word 
        if i == 2 : 

            # adding space to separate words 
            decipher += ' '
        else: 

            # accessing the keys using their values (reverse of 
encryption) 
            decipher += list(MORSE_CODE_DICT.keys())[list(MORSE_CODE_DICT 
            .values()).index(citext)] 
            citext = '' 

return decipher

def anagrams(word):
""" Generate all of the anagrams of a word. """ 
if len(word) < 2:
    yield word
else:
    for i, letter in enumerate(word):
        if not letter in word[:i]: #avoid duplicating earlier words
            for j in anagrams(word[:i]+word[i+1:]):
                yield j+letter
# Hard-coded driver function to run the program
while True:
    def main(): 


        message = input ("Type in Morse Code to output anagrams!: ")
        result = decrypt(message) 
        print (result)
        return result # return result
    for i in anagrams(main()):
        print (i)





# Executes the main function 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
main()
```

Comment: Outside of a programming context, that doesn't make any sense. Morse code wasn't invented until 1844, over 400 years after the Voynich Manuscript was created.

Comment: so, they would have written in modern Italian, coded in Morse?

Comment: I understand that however I believe Wilfrid Voynich constructed MS-408.

Comment: That's right njzk2 I believe Wilfrid wrote the glyphs down represented as Morse code and this cipher does work to find Italian words with an Italian anagram engine.  However the input is rather intense I sometime I need to make several attempts to retrieve some sort of narrative.

Answer (score 1):

Get a file of all Italian words, load the file into a Python `set`, and filter output words by checking whether they appear in the set.

For example, assuming you have a file `italian-words.txt` with one word on each line:

```
italian_words = set()
with open('italian-words.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        italian_words.add(line.strip())


output = []
for word in voynich_words:
    if word in italian_words:
        output.append(word)

print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks askaroni, can you please elaborate with a python coding example?

Comment: I see and thanks, but how would I integrate this with Morse code as the input, so that I can derive and Italian word as output?

Comment: First convert the morse code into words, which I'm calling `voynich_words` there.

Comment: askaroni, I'm going to use the code you provided above.